# imageOutput click within conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app in which users click on an image and this advances them to another image. This seems relatively straightforward, but before the user views the first image, they need to enter their email address. To achieve this, I have been using `conditionalPanel` where the first image is only displayed once the user hits an action button. However, when the panel for the images is embedded within the `conditionalPanel`, the `click` argument for `imageOutput` seems to stop working.

I have a directory named `images` with 9 images contained within it, with file names `1.png, 2.png...9.png` (by the way, if there is a way of uploading this directory to make this example more easily replicable, I'd be happy to take suggestions!). The following MWE -- which does not include the `conditionalPanel` element -- works well:

```
library(shiny)

## User interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("MWE",align="center"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, conditionalPanel(condition = "input.signingo == 0", 
                               wellPanel(
                             textInput("who",label = "Please enter your email address.", value=""),
                             actionButton("signingo",label="Go.")
                           ))
),

column(6, align="center",
                        wellPanel(
                          imageOutput("image", height = 175, width = 116, click = "photo_click")
                        )
)
  )

) 

server <- function(input, output){

  values <- reactiveValues(i = 0, selections = sample(1:9,1))

  ## Load image
  output$image <- renderImage({
filename <- normalizePath(file.path(paste0('images/',values$selections,".png")))

# Return a list containing the filename and alt text
list(src = filename,
     alt = paste(input$name))

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)

## Function to increment counter by one and to randomly select new image
  click.function <- function(){isolate({
    values$i <- values$i + 1
values$selections <- sample(1:9,1)
  })}

  ## Move on
  observeEvent(input$photo_click,{click.function() })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, when I include the `conditionalPanel` element, clicking on the image no longer seems to produce a new image. This is the code I am using:

```
  library(shiny)

  ## User interface
  ui <- fluidPage(
h1("MWE",align="center"),
fluidRow(
  column(4, conditionalPanel(condition = "input.signingo == 0", 
                             wellPanel(
                               textInput("who",label = "Please enter your email address.", value=""),
                               actionButton("signingo",label="Go.")
                             ))
  ),

  column(6, align="center",
         conditionalPanel(condition = "input.signingo > 0", 
                          wellPanel(
                            imageOutput("image", height = 175, width = 116, click = "photo_click")
                          ))
  )
)
)

  server <- function(input, output){

values <- reactiveValues(i = 0, selections = sample(1:9,1))

## Load image
output$image <- renderImage({
  filename <- normalizePath(file.path(paste0('images/',values$selections,".png")))

  # Return a list containing the filename and alt text
  list(src = filename,
       alt = paste(input$name))

}, deleteFile = FALSE)

## Function to increment counter by one and to randomly select new image
click.function <- function(){isolate({
  values$i <- values$i + 1
  values$selections <- sample(1:9,1)
})}

## Move on
observeEvent(input$photo_click,{click.function() })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem is that although the first `conditionalPanel` seems to be doing its job -- the user sees the "Please enter your email address" first, and only sees the first image after clicking "Go" -- clicking on the image no longer advances the user forward to the next image. Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing purposes I generated 9 png files with numbers from 1 to 9 using the following code

```
for (i in 1:9) {
  #png(paste0(i, ".png"), bg = "grey") # you can manipulate the size of graphics 
  png(paste0(i, ".png"), bg = "grey", height = 400, width = 400) 
  plot(1:10, type = "n", axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "")
  text(5,5, i, cex = 15, col = i)
  box()
  dev.off()
}
```

I also made few changes in your code:

- Instead conditional panels there is a dynamic UI which depends on `value$i`
- Initially `value$i` is set to `-1` and `textInput` and a button are showed
- If the user inputs a character string which contains `@` and presses the button, the value of `value$i` is incremented by 1 and the plotOutput is shown.
- If there the inputed character string doesn't contain `@` a warning is shown (`shinyBS`)

---

The problem is somehow caused by resizing `plotOutput` using parameters `height` and `width`. The `input$photo_click` doesn't then return a value or more precisely it returns `NULL`. If the plot is not resized everything works perfectly. So one of the solutions is to put `plotOutput` inside a `div` and using very simple `CSS`    to set the desired size of the output.

You can resize the div as follows:

```
div(style = "background:red; height: 400; width: 400;", 
            imageOutput("image", click = "photo_click")
          )
```

You can play with the values of `height` and `width` within a div and with the size of the png files to get a desired result.

```
 ... 
 png(paste0(i, ".png"), bg = "grey", height = 400, width = 400) 
 ...
```

The background colour is set to be red and png files are grey to make easier the positioning.

I hope that this solution will be helpful to you:

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

## User interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("dynamic")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){


  output$dynamic <- renderUI({
    if (values$i == -1) { 
      list(
        h1("MWE", align = "center"),
        wellPanel(
           textInput("who", label = "Please enter your email address.", value = ""),
           actionButton("signingo", label = "Go."),
           bsAlert("alert")
        )
      )
    }
    else {
      fluidRow(
        column(4),
        column(6,
          # imageOutput("image", height = 175, width = 116, click = "photo_click")
          # Setting a custom height and width causes the problem.

          # You can wrap imageOutput into a div. 
          div(style = "background:red; height: 400; width: 400;", 
            imageOutput("image", click = "photo_click")
          )
        )
      )
    }
  })

  # values$i changed to -1
  values <- reactiveValues(i = -1, selections = sample(1:9,1))

  ## Load image
  output$image <- renderImage({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path(paste0('images/',values$selections,".png")))
    #filename <- paste0("/Users/User/Downloads/images/", values$selections, ".png")

    # Return a list containing the filename and alt text
    # list(src = filename,
    #      alt = paste(input$name)) # I don't know what is input$name

    list(src = filename,
         alt = paste(values$i))

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)

  ## Function to increment counter by one and to randomly select new image
  click.function <- function(){ # isolate({
    values$i <- values$i + 1
    values$selections <- sample(1:9,1)
  # })
}

  # increment once values$i (from -1 to 0) to close the first menu.
  observeEvent(input$signingo, {
    #if (input$who != "") 
    # Require that the inputed string includes @
    if (gregexpr(pattern = "@", input$who) != -1) { 
      click.function()
      closeAlert(session, "Alert")

    } else {
      # If the inputed string doesen't contain @ create a warning
      createAlert(session, "alert", "Alert", title = "Not valid email",
                  content = "", dismiss = T, style = "warning")
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$photo_click, {
    click.function() 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for being so thorough.